# ¿Como agrego en un DataGridView datos de varias tablas usando Entity Framework con WPF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf, entity-framework-6, datagridview

Primero que nada, estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto con un ABM simple usando Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) y Entity Framework que me sirva como muestra para mi trabajo.

Hice una base de datos local con SQL Server en mi PC para usar con este proyecto y le cree las tablas `Cliente`, `TipoPago`, `ListaPrecios` y `CondicionIVA`.
Estas ultimas 3 lo unico que tienen son ID y Descripcion, en cambio la tabla `Cliente` tiene los siguientes campos:

> NroCli
>   NomCli
>   NomFantasia
>   Domicilio
>   Telefono
>   Email
>   ConIva (Se relaciona con el campo Id de la tabla CondicionIva)
>   TipoPago (Se relaciona con el campo Id de la tabla TipoPago)
>   ListaPrecios (Se relaciona con el campo Id de la tabla ListaPrecios )

En mi proyecto tengo una ventana a la que le agregué un `DataGridView` que está definido de la siguiente manera:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgClientes" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,10">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nro Cliente" Binding="{Binding Path=NroCli}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre" Binding="{Binding Path=NomCli}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre de Fantasía" Binding="{Binding Path=NomFantasia}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Domicilio" Binding="{Binding Path=Domicilio}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Telefono" Binding="{Binding Path=Telefono}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="e-Mail" Binding="{Binding Path=Email}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ConIva" Binding="{Binding Path=ConIva}" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Hidden"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Condicion de IVA" Binding="{Binding Path=Descripcion}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="TipoPago" Binding="{Binding Path=TipoPago}" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Hidden"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tipo de Pago" Binding="{Binding Path=Descripcion}" IsReadOnly="True" ></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ListaPrecios" Binding="{Binding Path=ListaPrecios}" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Hidden"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lista de Precios" Binding="{Binding Path=Descripcion}" IsReadOnly="True" ></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Pero el problema que tengo es que no sé como hacer para que me muestre las descripciones de "Condicion de IVA", "Tipo de Pago" y "Lista de Precios", ya que este `DataGridView` lo completo de la siguiente manera:

```
private void ArmaGrilla()
{
    using (EntityDB db = new EntityDB())
    {
        dgClientes.ItemsSource = db.Clientes.ToList<Clientes>();
    }
}
```

De esta forma me muestra los datos de la tabla `Cliente` sin problema alguno, pero no sé cómo hacer para que me muestre también los otros 3 datos que me faltan.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que tu problema es que no sabes como hacer una consulta al estilo "sql" con `JOINS` con **EntityFramework**, para ello puedes consultar directamente los datos al DataContext de EntityFramework usando `LinQ`, y cargar el `DataGrid` con el resultado.

Primero agrega una variable de clase (para reutilizarla) llamada "contexto" que haga referencia al `DataContext` de `EntityFramework`, el nombre del `DataContext` lo puedes encontrar en el `designer.cs` del archivo `.dbml`, lo verás como constructor de esa clase.

```
myProjectDataContext contexto = new myProjectDataContext();
```

Ahora ya puedes hacer la consulta:

```
private void CargarDataGrid()
{
    var result = (from c in contexto.Cliente
        from p in contexto.CondicionIVA.Where(x => x.Id == c.ConIva)
        from t in contexto.TipoPago.Where(y => y.Id == c.TipoPago)
        from l in contexto.ListaPrecios.Where(x => x.Id == c.ListaPrecios)
        //where
        //c.NroCli > 0 &&
        //l.Id > 0
        //orderby c.PERSONA ascending
        select new
        {
            NroCli = c.NroCli, //Así le cambias el HEADER a la columna..(ejemplo)
            c.NomCli,
            c.NomFantasia,
            c.Domicilio,
            c.Telefono,
            c.Email,
            c.ConIva,
            c.TipoPago,
            c.ListaPrecios,
            p.Campo1,
            p.Campo2,
            t.Campo1,
            t.Campo2,
            l.Campo1,
            l.Campo2
        });
        dgClientes.DataSource = result.ToList();
}
```

Ahora claro, el resultado no será una `List` de un tipo de dato o clase específica (obviamente), el resultado será una lista de tipo `AnonymousType`.

Si quieres obtener los valores de las celdas de la fila que selecciones puedes hacerlo así:

```
private void dgClientes_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
    var fila = senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    //Así puedes obtener los valores de las celdas (Ejemplo)
    int NRO_CLI = Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells[0].Value.ToString());  
}
```

Recuerda manejar bien las propiedades del `DataGrid`, desactivando `AutoGenerateColumns` para que no duplique columnas.

Y ya con eso deberías tener solucionado tu problema.
Saludos y suerte!